# Taking a numpy array and filing rows of a QStandardItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using a numpy array that contains the following data

```
split_data_array = [['bird', '0.40', '0.38', '0.40', '0.36', '0.47'], 
                    ['bird', '0.34', '0.31', '0.34', '0.43', '0.56'],
                    ['bird', '0.30', '0.23', '0.25', '0.52', '0.64'],
                    ['bird', '0.42', '0.36', '0.39', '0.52', '0.64'],
                    ['bird', '0.37', '0.39', '0.43', '0.51', '0.62'],
                    ['bird', '0.32', '0.50', '0.54', '0.52', '0.64'],
                    ['bird', '0.35', '0.77', '0.82', '0.51', '0.59'],
                    ['bird', '0.32', '0.22', '0.29', '0.50', '0.79']]
```

I am attempting to use a `QTableView` with a `QStandardItemModel` so that I can display the data. I'm confused as how to take the data and have it populate the rows in my `QTableView`. Currently my code is set up for the table and the `QStandardItemModel`.

```
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.number_rows, 6) # Set rows, columns
model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
    ["Object", "Confidence %", "XMin", "YMin", "XMax", "YMax"])  # Set labels

self.ui.statsTableView.setModel(model)
self.ui.statsTableView.setSelectionMode(
    QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
self.ui.statsTableView.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the items, on the other hand set the number of rows to 0 to add it line by line.

```py
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 6, self) 
model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Object", "Confidence %", "XMin", "YMin", "XMax", "YMax" ])
for d in split_data_array:
    its = []
    for v in d:
        its.append(QtGui.QStandardItem(v))
    model.appendRow(its)
```